# Again, the same error ' ahorcado.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'beginPath' of undefined'

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a Hangman game, but im so n00b that i dont get where is the error on my code, im glad if you can help me, (Sorry for my bad english.)

```
var hombre;

var Ahorcado = function (con) {
    this.contexto = con;
    this.maximo = 5;
    this.intentos = 0;

    this.dibujar();
}

Ahorcado.prototype.dibujar = function () {

    var dibujo = this.contexto;

    dibujo.beginPath();
    dibujo.moveTo(150,100);
    dibujo.lineTo(150,50);
    dibujo.lineTo(400,50);
    dibujo.lineTo(400,350);
    dibujo.strokeStyle = '#000'
    dibujo.stroke();
    dibujo.closePath();
}



function iniciar() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 400;
    var contexto = canvas.getContext('2d');
    hombre = new Ahorcado();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function takes a parameter`con` in  `var Ahorcado = function (con) {...}`

When you call `hombre = new Ahorcado()`, you are forgetting to pass in your `contexto` variable.

Change it to:

```
function iniciar() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 400;
    var contexto = canvas.getContext('2d');
    hombre = new Ahorcado(contexto); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, your solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
var contexto = canvas.getContext('2d');
hombre = new Ahorcado();
```

You forgot to pass in the context to the constructor